# Fatal error: w2c/c-auto.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, alpine-linux

When trying to build the syntax in alpine 3.18 linux, shows error:

```
git clone https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex.git
cd syntex
gcc -c -fPIC *.c
```

shows error:

```
synctex_main.c:71:17: fatal error: w2c/c-auto.h: No such file or directory
   71 | #       include <w2c/c-auto.h>
```

Am I missing something? which package should I install?

Answer (score 2):

The include of the file `w2c/c-auto.h` is controlled by macro `__SYNCTEX_WORK__` ([source](https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex/blob/91d69b73e2fc9c65953c04debe0f06fbd1e51299/synctex_main.c#L67)):

```c
#   ifdef __SYNCTEX_WORK__
#       include <synctex_parser_c-auto.h>
/*      for inline && HAVE_xxx */
#   else
#       include <w2c/c-auto.h>
/*      for inline && HAVE_xxx */
#   endif
```

Try to specify this option to a compiler: `-D__SYNCTEX_WORK__`